# "scrollRestoration" set to manual and swipe back functionality on Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, html5-history

`scrollRestoration` is awesome for single page apps.

I wanted to use this on my SPA, but one thing that made me change my mind is the iOS swipe back gesture that shows a white background in the back (sneak peek) and once the swipe is made nothing happens for 2-3 seconds.

**Desired**: show previous state or disable the gesture with all.

If you want to see this behaviour you can check the view screen capture linked bellow or check https://mobile.twitter.com on your iPhone.

Any ideas on how to achieve the desired behaviour mentioned above?

Current behaviour: http://recordit.co/rn5ORRtICg